# Vee Validate Only Validating Last Item

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I inherited a Vue site with a form that was experiencing heavy input lag using Vee Validate 2.x.

I migrated to 3.2.4 (vue 2.6.10) and followed the migration guide, but am only seeing the validation check my final input.

This is an amended version of the code:

```js
<ValidationObserver ref="form">
    <form @submit.prevent="submit">
         <div v-for="formField in form.fields">
              <ValidationProvider name="formField.label" rules="required" v-if="formField.type != 'select'" v-slot="v">
                   <input 
                      :type="formField.type"
                      :placeholder="formField.placeholder"
                      v-model="formField.value"
                   >
                   <span class="text _warning" >{{ v.errors[0] }}</span>
               </ValidationProvider>

               <ValidationProvider name="formField.label" rules="required" v-if="formField.type == 'select'" v-slot="v">
                    <select v-model="formField.value" class="content_input input -select -arrow">
                        <option :value="null" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select {{formField.label}}</option>
                        <option v-bind:value="option.value" v-for="option in formField.options" :value="option.value" >{{option.label}}</option>
                    </select>
                    <span class="text _warning" >{{ v.errors[0] }}</span>
               </ValidationProvider>
         </div>
         <button class="button input" type="submit"> 
             {{form.data.submitText}}
         </button>
      </div>
   </form>
</ValidationObserver>

import { extend } from 'vee-validate';
import { required, email } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules';

extend('email', email);

extend('required', {
   ...required,
  message: 'This field is required'
});

export default {
...
    methods: {
        submit() {
            this.$refs.form.validate().then(success => {
                if(!success) {
                    return;
                }
                ...
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very minor mistake - the `ValidationProvider` components need to be provided unique names, and you have set the attribute `name="formField.label"` which sets it to the string "formField.label".  What you meant to do is set it to `:name="formField.label"` (note the extra colon).  Once you do that it will work.

Comment: note that you can use `vid` rather than `name` if you don't want to override the `name` (for example if you use the `name` field for display in the error messages) (src: https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/advanced/cross-field-validation.html#targeting-other-fields)

Comment: if someone has to use same name for more than one fields, then they have to provide "vid" with unique value for all those same name fields, then vee validate will show error message for all same name fields.